# Pandas: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert columns from unicode to str.
I try

```
f.edge(str(group['subdomain']).iloc[i], str(group['subdomain'].iloc[i+1]),
           label=str(group['search_term'].iloc[i+1]))
```

But it returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'`
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting before accessing the `iloc` attribute:

```
str(group['subdomain']).iloc[i]
#                     ^
```

Move the parenthesis farther to the right:

```
str(group['subdomain'].iloc[i])
```

Comment: Can you help with this problem? `Error: Edge length 208568.346597 larger than maximum 65535 allowed.
Check for overwide node(s).`

Comment: @ldevyataykina It's hard to tell what the problem really is without a traceback and the related code. You may consider asking this as a new question.